# Designer fails to get good style on Window Custom Control

Tags: wpf, themes, custom-controls, designer

Here is my problem:
I have created a window custom control.

```
public class NxChromeWindow : Window
```

Then i have in my generic resource in the default theme:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type windows:NxChromeWindow}">
```

I have 2 windows instances in my app: windows:NxChromeWindow and the Window.

When running all works OK. I see 2 different styles but when using the designer or blend.
something very weird happens:

The designer takes the style of windows:NxChromeWindow and applies it to both the windows:NxChromeWindow and the normal window.

I don't understand how is this possible. How can it apply a subClass style to a base class?I clearly gave the TargetType="{x:Type windows:NxChromeWindow}" so i don't understand how Window get the same style in the designer.

Do you have an idea?

Joao

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the static constructor of NxChromeWindow:

```
static NxChromeWindow()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NxChromeWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(NxChromeWindow)));
}
```